# What is the liquid that Ronan comes out of in his introduction?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

When Ronan makes his spectacular and violent appearance on *Guardians of the Galaxy*, he comes out from a covered hole fill with some sort of liquid. He is in this liquid hole in the foetus position.

Knowing that this hole is completely fill and sealled shut:

1. **What is this liquid and how can he survive in that ?**
   [image]
2. **To add a bit more, why does he get covered in sand before being
   clothed ?**
   [image]

Comment: It's heavily implied to be the blood of dead Xandarians.

Comment: And more importantly, why can’t I buy delicious fresh Ronanjuice in my local supermarket?

Comment: @Keen Means, there's no upper limit of madness.

Comment: LOL delicious RonanJuice.  Freshly squeezed i hope. :)

Comment: Evil-Preservation-Goo-3000ᵗᵐ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the blood of dead Xandarians, as is evident from the very next scene.

Ronan The Accuser kills a captive Xandarian on the platform, after which the blood is shown to flow back into the circular chamber from which Ronan had risen at the beginning.

[image: Ronan slaying the Xandarian.] [image: The Xandarian blood drain.]

Comment: i just look back at the scene and that is true :D thx... we even see Ronan on his knee and watching the blood entering that hole.. i had never realise that and the reason is simple... when the liquid slowly slip away there is none of it that sticks to Ronans body as (in my mind) blood is suppose to be thick and sticky. We even see that it looks like thick and sticky when it runs down the (hotel) after Ronan smash the Xandorian's head

Comment: Apparently alien blood doesn't coagulate. That must suck for paper cuts

Comment: @cde - well it's as they say, smashed heads don't coagulate :P

Comment: The sand may be some sort of ritual, or it may simply be an alternative to towels. Some cultures used to use sand for drying purposes - after the sand soaked up the wetness, they wiped off the sand. Sounds gritty, but it's true.